# Why Java Automatic modules do not contain exports section

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

There is a mechanism to convert regular jar into an [automatic module](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules) starting from [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9), by simple placing it onto `modulepath` instead of `classpath`. An automatic module has the following properties:

> An automatic module is a named module that is defined implicitly,
>   since it does not have a module declaration. Every package in an
>   automatic module is, therefore, considered to be exported even if it
>   might actually be intended only for internal use.

So all packages inside an automatic module are available. But if we inspect an automatic module with `--describe-module` directive there is no `exports` section in the output.

For example an automatic module `main`

```
jar --file main.jar --describe-module
com.foo jar:file:///.../code/module/main.jar/!module-info.class
requires java.base mandated
contains com.foo
```

Why is there no `exports` section if package `com.foo` is considered to be exported anyway? I find this a bit confusing: `--describe-module` suggests that there are **no exported packages**, but at the same time, `main` is an automatic module so everything is **exported implicitly**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, the command line option `--describe-module` within the `jar` tool is just to describe what the jar file is about, if its an explicit module the complete descriptor is shared whie for automatic module just the name is depicted.

Quoting from the command `jar --help`

> Print the module descriptor, ***or*** automatic module name

---

On the other hand, if you [try using `jdeps` for generating `module-info.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm#GUID-A543FEBE-908A-49BF-996C-39499367ADB4__MODULEDEPENDENCEANALYSISOPTIONS-18405357) of an automatic module given a jar file, you can notice that such packages exports are actually present in the module declaration. Say for example:

```
jdeps -verbose:class --generate-module-info ../Desktop  ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
```

writes to `.../Desktop/org.apache.commons.lang3/module-info.java` the following

```
module org.apache.commons.lang3 {
    requires transitive java.desktop;

    exports org.apache.commons.lang3;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.arch;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.builder;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.event;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.exception;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.math;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.text;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.time;
    exports org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple;
}
```

Comment: `for automatic module just the name is depicted.`  it looks like this is not the only information provided for automatic module. There is information about contained packages and required modules. But not the exported packages. Still it is a bit confusing that this info is missing. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc The info that you say is missing might have been intentionally omitted since automatic modules are just a path to migration and not supposedly be a future requirement for any modular project that uses them. So listing a `module-info.class` while describing them might just be a little too much information telling the consumer, that *"hey I have a descriptor here, go ahead and use it."* ... Instead, I would rely on the current implementation and tell the consumers, that *"I am an automatic module, you should keep an eye on my updates for modular releases."* <~Just an opinion

Comment: The output of the jar tool is correct. The details of the module derived for JAR files on the module path without a module-info.class is in the ModuleFinder spec. Automatic modules received special treatment at both compile-time and run-time so they work as if all packages are exported and open.